# How to say one is valid or invalid even though one is and the other is not?

Tags: c++

I need it to say the numbers are valid if both of them are valid and invalid if both of them are invalid and if one is valid and the other isn't, it needs it to say which is valid and which isn't

I tried the code below and it just keeps saying both valid or invalid even if one of them is invalid and the second is valid

so if both are valid I want it to say: they are valid

if both are invalid: they are invalid

if one is valid and the other isn't it should say whether they are valid or not

```
if ((Q == 100 || Q == 400) && (W == 100 || W == 400))
    cout << "they are invalid\n";
else if (!((Q == 100 || Q == 400) && (W == 100 || W == 400))) //else if ((Q != 100 && Q != 400) && (W != 100 && W != 400)) //
    cout << "they are valid\n";
else {
    if (Q == 100 || Q == 400)
        cout << "Q is invalid";
    else
        cout << "Q is valid";

    if (W == 100 || W == 400)
        cout << "W is invalid\n";
    else
        cout << "W is valid\n";
}
```

I expected it to say:

```
Q is invalid
W is valid
```

when W==200 and Q==400

Comment: Think about your second `if` condition. Your first condition checks whether both are invalid. Your second condition negates that check, so it's effectively checking whether the variables are not both invalid.

Comment: @melpomene Is that wrong? I mean the next step is to check if both are valid.

Comment: @Mike "not both invalid" is not the same thing as "both not invalid" (i.e. "both valid").

Comment: @melpomene can you elaborate a bit more on what you said:                           
   not both invalid" is not the same thing as "both not invalid"

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do this. Here is how to do it.

- set a variable to 0 ; say it is x
- if q is valid then set the low order bit of x
- if w is valid set the second to lowest bit of x
- if x=0 print both are invalid
- if x=1 print q is valid w is invalid
- if x=2 print q is invalid w is valid
- if x=3 print both are valid

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int  Q, W;
    cin >> Q >> W;
    if ((Q == 100 || Q == 400) && (W == 100 || W == 400)){
        cout << "they are invalid\n";
        return 0;
    }else if ((Q != 100 && Q != 400) && (W != 100 && W != 400)){
        cout << "they are valid\n";
        return 0;
    }
    if (Q == 100 || Q == 400)
            cout << "Q is invalid" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Q is valid" << endl;
    if (W == 100 || W == 400)
            cout << "W is invalid\n";
        else
            cout << "W is valid\n";
}
```

Comment: You should only use a runnable snippet if the code can be executed by that snippet. Besides that, you have to explain what you have changed, and why this solves the problem. Just posting some code without any explanation is not really helpfull.

Comment: @t.niese sorry for that. Im new to coding and stack overflow and i didnt know about it. thx for informing. i will try to use a snippet

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is going wrong you need to check what the result of your logical operator is for `W=200` and `Q=400`:

```
( // !false => true
  !( // true && false => false
     (Q == 100 || Q == 400) && // true
     (W == 100 || W == 400)    // false
   )
)
```

But you want that both `(Q == 100 || Q == 400)` and `(W == 100 || W == 400)` are `false`, so you want to write:

```
(
  (
     ! (Q == 100 || Q == 400) &&
     ! (W == 100 || W == 400)
   )
)
```

If you now want to move the `!` out of the brace then you need to change the `&&` to `||`.

```
(
  !(
      (Q == 100 || Q == 400) ||
      (W == 100 || W == 400)
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making the code easier to read, then you don't have to deal with the more complex boolean algebra. You can do that by introducing helper variables:

```
const bool q_is_valid = Q != 100 && Q != 400;
const bool w_is_valid = W != 100 && W != 400;
```

Now the rest becomes much simpler to write and to read:

```
if (q_is_valid && w_is_valid) {
    cout << "Both are valid.\n";
} else if (!q_is_valid && !w_is_valid) {
    cout << "Both are invalid.\n";
} else {
    cout << "Q is " << (q_is_valid ? "valid" : "invalid") << ".\n"
         << "W is " << (w_is_valid ? "valid" : "invalid") << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: thx for the help. i really dont know how to use boolean well so i try to learn it but anyways thanks it helped me to solve my homework